# How to configure in Apache an exception to password protection for a CakePhp App?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, password-protection, locationmatch

I have a CakePHP Application which I want to protect with a password. The tricky thing is, that all files/locations should be only accessible with a password EXCEPT one specific Address (a function withing a CakePHP-controller)

The Address is like that:

> http://example.com/MyApp/MyController/MyFunction?MyParam=MyValue

All other locations should be only accessible with a password

> http://example.com/MyApp/MyController/MyOtherFunction
>   http://example.com/MyApp/MyController/MyOtherFunction
>   http://example.com/MyApp/MyOtherController/MyOtherFunction

Well, I tried it first in the root `.htaccess`-File, but the whole rewrite-thing of CakePHP makes it very difficult and in .htaccess-Files are no `<LocationMatch>` directive allowed. So I tried it with `<FilesMatch>`, but the real File is always the same: `index.php`. mod_rewrite rewrites all Addresses to

> http://example.com/MyApp/app/webroot/index.php?url=$1

In the next step I tried it in the apache-configuration and put there this section

```
<LocationMatch ^/MyApp/MyController/MyFunction.*>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Secure Area"
  AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
  Require user MyUser
</LocationMatch>
```

Well the regex matched, but it was the wrong way. It protects MyFunction but not the rest.

Comment: I think you just need to invert the meaning of your regexp pattern.  I can't find a simple way of doing that, although it does appear that the caret means both "match from start of string" and "invert pattern".  I'm just not 100% sure the syntax for inverting the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using .htpasswd? You might be better using Cake Auth, then you can do this in the appropriate controller:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('MyFunction');
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming OP has a reason they want to use htpasswd protection rather than a login system.  But I'm with you -- I would put this into the application logic, so you can better control the user session.

Comment: First I thought using .htpasswd will be easier... Now I use Cake Auth and it works with allow(). Thanks